# Removing given range of letters from a sequence

Tags: perl, excel

**FILE1**

```
1   M   S   S   N   S   D   T   G   D   L   Q   E   S   L   K   H   G   L   T   P   I   G   A   G   L   P   D   R   H   G   S   P   I   P   A   R   G   R   L   V   M   L   P   K   V   E   T   E   A   L   G   L   A   R   S   H  

2   M   H   S   S   N   P   K   V   R   S   S   P   S   G   N   T   Q   S   S   P   K   S   K   Q   E   V   M   V   R   P   P   T   V   M   S   P   S   G   N   P   Q   L   D   S   K   F   S   N     

3   M   N   G   H   S   D   E   E   S   V   R   N   S   S   G   E   S   S   Q   S   D   D   D   S   G   S   A   S   G   S   G   S   G   S   S   S   G   S   S   S   D   G   S
```

**FILE2**

**1** 9 24  36  40
**2** 1 14  19  35
**3** 8 37

***Desired output***

File 2 contains tab delimited numbers every two numbers in all rows are the ranges of letters which are needed to be removed from respective sequence (tab delimited file 1).  e.g. for sequence 1, I need to print letter from 1 to 8 *(not 9 to 24)*, 25 to 35 *(not 36 to 40)*, and 41 to end of peptide.

***My code (not perfect)***

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
open( FH, "a.txt" );
@seq = <FH>;
open( FH1, "b.txt" );
@num = <FH1>;
open( OUT, ">out.txt" );
@seqs = split( /\n/, "@seq" );
@nums = split( /\n/, "@num" );

foreach $new (@nums) {
    @num1 = split( '\t', $new );
    $n1   = $num1[1];
    $n2   = $num1[2];
    $n3   = $num1[3];
    $n4   = $num1[4];
}
foreach $old (@seqs) {
    @seq1 = split( '\t', $old );
    $len = @seq1;
    print OUT"@seq1[0..$n1,$n2..$n3,$n4..$len]";
}
close FH;
close FH1;
close OUT;
```

**NOTE: original files are much much larger and split may go *out of memory***

Comment: how is your code failing? An exception? Incorrect behavior? How far have you got debugging?

Comment: It is removing letters from sequence but not as per file2 numbers, I guess random.

Comment: ok, start to debug, locate the problem.

Comment: Have you though about using a hash of arrays?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, always use `use warnings;` **AND** `use strict;`. `use Data::Dumper;` would really help you here.

Also, you can remove the redundant `-w (warnings)` flag from your shebang line.

```
> original files are much much larger and split may go out of memory
```

You shouldn't read the whole file into memory: `@array = <FH>;`

Instead you should go line by line: `while (my $line = <$FH>) {`

Which brings us to another issue... You should use the 3-arg lexically scoped `open`.

```
open my $fh, ">", $file;
```

The next thing, `@nums = split( /\n/, "@num");` has a few issues.

1. lose the quotes around the variable.
2. @nums is going to contain the number of lines, and that's it.

So once you've fixed all this....

Your logic looks wrong with the `foreach` loops.

Why are you hard-coding 4 values, when the contents of each line in the file are NOT the same? Meaning on the last pass, there will only be 2 values and you're assigning 4 from the `split`.

Seems like you mean to be operating on each array simultaneously...

E.g.,

```
# While array != null

# # read nums array for indecies to skip

# # grab same row of data to print missing values you want skipped

# # print data to output file...

# end
```

To be honest, I would fix/rewrite this whole script. Then come back here if you're still having issues.

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful, I am quite weak at foreach logic. please help.